# Windows 2008 DNS Export all A Records

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I know about dnscmd /enumrecords, however what I want to do is export all records from every single zone housed on this server.

I was hoping there was a simple recursive function to do this. We have 100s of DNS zones on our server, so I'm not about to run a 'dnscmd /enumrecords' manually for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this steps: [Windows DNS Export Import](http://robiulislam.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/windows-dns-export-import/)

I don't have a lot of zones but quite a lot of registries on each one.

---

UPDTATE (solution explanation)

---

### Exporting

1. Export all your zones for your own safety:

   `C:\> dnscmd servername /enumrecords zonename @ /type A /detail > c:\filename.txt`
2. Export the registry records:

   Run REGEDIT and navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\DNS Server\Zones`
   (Right-Click the key ZONES and export to a .reg file).

   or

   `C:\> regedit /e c:\dns.reg "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\DNS Server"`
3. Copy `*.dns` from: `%windir%\system32\dns`
4. Transfer all files t the new (target) server

### Importing

1. Create a test zone such as testdomain.com. The DNS server needs one zone created, but you can remove it after the import.
2. Copy the `*.dns` files into `%windir%\system32\dns` on the new server
3. Double click on the `.reg` file you created to load all the zones into the new server’s registry
   (*For Windows 2008: Right click the reg. file and run as Administrator*)
4. Restart the DNS Server service

Comment: We would prefer answers which describe the process, rather than simply linking to another document which might get deleted, moved or modified afterwards.

Comment: @EightBitTony I have updated to have the link and the full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [DNSShell](http://dnsshell.codeplex.com/) plugin for PowerShell.

Comment: I found the solution, very simple. dnscmd /zoneexport gets all the records in a zone into a text file.